# How to insert time interval between requests in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

How to insert time interval between the **completion** of the previous response and the start of the next request of 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. Insert [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler between requests and configure it to "Pause" for `3000` milliseconds

   [image]
2. Insert [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of the 2nd request, the timers are executed before each Sampler in their [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so it will introduce the 3 seconds delay between requests as well:

   [image]

   if you place the constant timer at the same level with those 2 samplers - it will create 3 seconds delay before each sampler